# Could not load file or assembly 'CopyModules.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, deployment, wpf-controls, cad, eyeshot

The published app that uses WPF controls of Eyeshot Ultimate 11 throws an exception with the following message when `devDept.Eyeshot.Translators.ReadAutodesk` is called:

> Could not load file or assembly 'CopyModules.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

The stack trace is shown here:

[image: this image].

`CopyModules.dll` is present in the application.

This exception is thrown in some computers but NOT in others.

We tried copying all dlls from `~\devDept Software\Eyeshot Ultimate 11\Bin\x86` to application's `bin` folder but that did not solve the issue.

Is there something we need to do to prevent this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package corresponding to the build architecture (x86 or x64) is required in end-user machines.

Comment: I installed Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable x86 Package for a x86 build and it solved the issue, thanks.